# Can't access data access layer on a wcf web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, wcf

I am calling a web service using jQuery ajax. I am getting internal server error.

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
public List<BrandModel> DoWork(int brandId)
{
    // here a receive a generic list of BrandModel by calling the static method FillModels. 
    List<BrandModel> models = DA.SupportData.FillModels(brandId);

    return models;
}
```

I've tried to omit the statement calling the data access layer and return a generic list created within the doWork method and it worked.

Comment: What does  `FillModel` do !??

Comment: access the database and returns a  generic list as LIst<BrandModel>. I am skipping the logic layer because I am testing.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause an internal server error - therefore, I suspect it's somewhere in your logic layer ...

Comment: [Activate tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to get more details about the error, or put the invocation of `FillModels` into a try-catch-block and log the error.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in my data access layer that was throwing a sql exception caused by cast from smallint to int. I revised my the data access code I thought that this conversion would be automatic. There's no problem calling a library class.